# Unable to import func A() of package main, inside another package main func main. There are 2 package main

Tags: go, go-packages

At package level `main` I have 2 files `hello.go` and `main.go`.

```
|- hello.go
|- main.go
```

Both the files are in `package main` level but unlike other packages I am unable to import a `func` defined in the `hello` in the `func main`. Can there be only 1 file with `package main`?

```
// hello.go
package main

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
  fmt.Println("hello world")
}

// main.go
package main 

func main() {
  Hello()
}
```

Error

```
./main.go:4:2: undefined: Hello
```

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: Never, literally **never** use `go run` in any other form than `go run .` (unless you _really_ understand how Go code is compiled and executed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal, you should use

```
go run .
```

instead of

```
go run main.go
```

Answer (score 1):

two ways to make this work ok

1. go build .   then execute the binary
2. with go mod:

> ```
>  go mod init main
>  go mod tidy
>  go run main
> ```

looks like build can resolve the module  to the current directory.
Otherwise, you have to tell go where the module is